# Magento 2 : How to solve the special characters in email subject?

Tags: magento2, email, transactional-mail, special-character

I'm having some issues related to special characters in my transactional emails, it looks like a native bug in Magento 2.1.7 (It seems still in 2.2.3)

**Steps to reproduce:**

I've set the store name as "Bob's Burgers" in the admin panel, then I go to the store frontend and go to **Request a password reset**, in order to receive an email including the store's name that I did the setup in the admin panel.

**Expected result:**

The email's subject should be **Reset your Bob's Burgers password** as I did the setup in the admin panel.

**Actual result:**

The subject is **Reset your Bob&#39;s Burgers password**

How could I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using this [reference on the Magento 2 Repository in Github](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8094), you can create a plugin to fix like that:

**di.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Email\Model\Template">
        <plugin name="mail_subject" type="VENDOR\MODULE\Plugin\Template" sortOrder="100" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**Template.php**

```
namespace VENDOR\MODULE\Plugin;

class Template
{
    public function afterGetSubject(
        \Magento\Email\Model\Template $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        return htmlspecialchars_decode((string)$result, ENT_QUOTES);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works! Thanks! This is still a bug in Magento 2.2.3...